# Search in linked list with possibly more results

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My semester project is to write a program for telephone book. I'm 3/4 done, but I need to create a modify function, to be able to modify records in my linked list. My question is, that in a telephone book it's possible, that more than one people have the same name, but other telnumber.

In my function the program asks for the name that's wanted to be modified, but if someone search for a name that exists more than once, then how am I able to make a choice between them, which of them is the wanted person?

My struct of the linked list:

```
typedef struct szemely {
     char *veznev;
     char *kernev;
     char *telnum;
     char *varos;        
     struct szemely *next;
 } Person;
```

Comment: You could present the user with a list of search results and ask again to identify the record he wants to modify.

Comment: The program can't guess, so the obvious answer is make the user choose. Or, make it so there can't be two contacts with the same name to begin with.

Comment: @Havenard, so you're saying there should only be one John Smith per phonebook?

Comment: @fbynite You can alias them, "John Smith (Work)", "John Smith (Mechanic)",  "John Smith (Bank Manger)". And normally you would, sometimes even if there was only one person with that name, after all you're not supposed to remember who everyone in your list is and why they are even in there, those notes are not only extremely helpful but also solve this problem.

Comment: @Havenard, so you're saying you can only have mechanic named John Smith?

Comment: @fbynite You will have to find out some way to tell them apart arent you? If "John Smith (Mechanic)" calls you but you know a dozen, how are you supposed to know who is calling you?

Answer (score 0):

Display a list of possible choices and have the operator pick which one, either by number, in a terminal, or through other interface selection methods (button, link, checkbox, or the like).

What interface will the program be targeting?

Answer (score 0):

The `modify` function won't handle the search at all.  You'll need (want) a separate function for the name search, call it `person_lookup` or something.

There's a few things you want to do.

1. person lookup by name
2. show lookup results to user
3. accept user selection (i.e. the user will select a person from a numbered list)
4. modify that person's information that the user selected.

psuedo-code:

```
struct Person *person;
struct Person *persons;

/* return a list of names or NULL if none are found */
persons = lookup_person(name)

if (persons is NULL)
     handle_no_results_found && return;

/* user_selection_from() will display the matched lookup names 
 * as a numbered list. The user will select a number from the 
 * list that corresponds to a name.
 */
person = user_selection_from(persons);

/* the user didn't select a name from the list */
if (person is NULL)
      handle_no_user_selection && return;

/* modify the person the user selected */
error = modify(person);

if (error) 
     alert_user_unable_to_modify_person;
```

As I said, this is psuedo-code, not entirely correct - but it should give you an idea or (hopefully) put you on the right path.